# Postgres locks within a transaction

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking, postgresql-9.4

I'm having trouble understanding how locks interact with transactions in Postgres.

When I run this (long) query, I am surprised by the high degree of locking that occurs:

```
BEGIN;
TRUNCATE foo;
\COPY foo FROM 'backup.txt';
COMMIT;
```

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) for `\COPY` doesn't mention what level of lock it requires, but [this post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/10611.1014867684%40sss.pgh.pa.us) indicates that it only gets a RowExclusiveLock. But when I run this query during the `\COPY`:

```
SELECT mode, granted FROM pg_locks
WHERE relation='foo'::regclass::oid;
```

I get this:

```
mode    granted
RowExclusiveLock    true
ShareLock   true
AccessExclusiveLock true
```

Where the heck is that AccessExclusiveLock coming from? I assume it's coming from the `TRUNCATE`, which [requires an AccessExclusiveLock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html). But the `TRUNCATE` finishes quickly, so I'd expect the lock to release quickly as well. This leaves me with a few questions.

When a lock is acquired by a command within a transaction, is that lock released at the end of the command (before the end of the transaction)? If so, why do I observe the above behavior? If not, why not? In fact, since [transactions don't touch the table until the `COMMIT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188911/how-to-delete-many-rows-from-frequently-accessed-table#comment-59698242), why does a `TRUNCATE` in a transaction need to block the table at all?

I don't see any discussion of this in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-begin.html) for [transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) in PG.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a couple of misconceptions to be cleared up here.

**First**, a transaction *does* touch the table before it is committed. The comment you are quoting says that a `ROLLBACK` (and a `COMMIT` as well) don't touch the table, which is something different. They record the transaction state in the *commit log* (in `pg_clog`), and `COMMIT` flushes the transaction log to disk (one notable exception to this is `TRUNCATE`, which is relevant for your question: the old table is kept around until the end of the transaction and gets deleted during `COMMIT`).

If all changes were held back until `COMMIT` and no locks would be taken, `COMMIT` would be quite expensive and would routinely fail because of concurrent modifications. The transaction would have to remember the state of the database as it was before and check if the changes still apply. This way of handling concurrency is called [*optimistic concurreny control*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control), and while it is a decent strategy for an application, it won't work well for a relational database, where `COMMIT` should be efficient and should not fail (unless there are major problems with the infrastructure).

So what relational databases use is *pessimistic concurrency control* or *locking*, i.e. they lock a database object before they access it to prevent concurrent activity from getting in their way.

**Second**, relational databases use [*two-phase locking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking), in which locks (at least the user-visible, so-called *heavyweight locks*) are always held until the end of the transaction.
This is necessary (but not sufficient) to keep transactions in a logical order (*serializable*) and consistent. What if you release a lock, and somebody else removes the row that your inserted, but uncommitted row refers to via a foreign key constraint?

**Answer to the question**

The upshot of all this is that your table will keep the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock from `TRUNCATE` until the end of the transaction. Isn't it evident why that is necessary? If other transactions were allowed to even read the table after the (as of yet uncommitted) `TRUNCATE`, they would find it empty, since `TRUNCATE` really empties the table and does not adhere to [*MVCC*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) semantics. Such a [*dirty read*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Dirty_reads) (of uncommitted data that might yet be rolled back) cannot be allowed.

If you really need read access to the table during the refill, you could use `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE`. The downside is that this is a much more expensive operation that will leave the table with a lot of “dead tuples” that have to be removed by autovacuum, resulting in a lot of empty space (*table bloat*). But if you are willing to live with a table and indexes that are bloated such that table and index scans will take at least twice as long, it is an option.

Comment: Thanks, @Laurenz! I'm still struggling to grok how a `TRUNCATE` inside a transaction works, though. If "`TRUNCATE` really empties the table", and "`ROLLBACK` [doesn't] touch the table", then how does `TRUNCATE` get rolled back?

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding what you mean by "dirty read" (I see it mentioned in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html)), but that probably warrants its own question.

Comment: I explained "dirty read" and added a link. You are right that my explanation is a bit inconsistent when it comes to `TRUNCATE`. As described [in the code](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c;h=f97bee5b0e464265e2af103053800900f40058ff;hb=HEAD#l1214), the old table is not thrown away immediately, but at commit time, so in that case `COMMIT` does not exactly touch the table, but removes it. I'll try to make that clearer in my explanation.